# pytube ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```py
from pytube import YouTube
YouTube('https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download()
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:/Users/DARK/Desktop/projjject/test.py", line 2, in <module>
        YouTube('https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download()
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 92, in __init__
        self.descramble()
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 140, in descramble
        apply_signature(self.player_config_args, fmt, self.js)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 225, in apply_signature
        cipher = Cipher(js=js)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 31, in __init__
        var, _ = self.transform_plan[0].split(".")
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

i am getting this error when i try to use pytube. Pls help me to fix it.

Comment: Try to assign the `YouTube('https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0')` to a variable in order to debug and check the specific error in the following way: `yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0')` and afterwards perform the method to get the first stream available `stream = yt.streams.first()` and finally download the video with `stream.download()` in order to save it to the current working directory. Otherwise please explain your use case and check the [documentation](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#downloading-a-video) to see more examples.

Comment: if that doesn't work you can also try with the complete URL `yt = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0` and then perform the `streams.first()` and `download()` methods to download the Youtube video.

Comment: ```from pytube import YouTube
video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download()```

Comment: ```from pytube import YouTube
video = YouTube('https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download()

```

Comment: I'm getting the same error again

Comment: By checking the Github page for the library this seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/get-pytube/pytube3/issues/12). Notice that the library [doesn't seem to be currently maintained](https://github.com/get-pytube/pytube3/issues/99) and the current workaround would be to use [pytubeX](https://pypi.org/project/pytubeX/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this problem started a few days ago.
We will have to wait for the next update on pytube3.

Some time back, another problem occurred, which got solved in a few days.
https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/641

Answer (score 0):

Removing `pytube` and `pytube3` and installing [`pytubeX`](https://pypi.org/project/pytubeX/) instead—as suggested by Daniel Ocando—worked for me.